# Image source not binding in xamarin form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

My object has a property set elsewhere called:

```
ImageSrc = "icon.png"
```

In xaml file I am trying to bind to this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSrc}" />
```

In the ViewModel I am setting the property as such:

```
private string _imageSrc;

        public string ImageSrc
        {
            get => this._imageSrc;
            set
            {
                this._imageSrc = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ImageSrc);
            }
        }

public override Task InitializeAsync(object _params)
{
    ObjectParameters _objectParameters = (ObjectParameters)_params;
   
    this.ImageSrc = _objectParameters.ImageSrc;
    
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If I set this in class constructor:

```
this.ImageSrc = "icon.png";
```

it binds fine but not after calling:

```
public override Task InitializeAsync(object _params)
```

the property is set properly with the correct value of "icon.png" but the image does not show like when set in the class constructor. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: yes, it is done through here: this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ImageSrc); which sets other properties as well throughout the app without issues.

Comment: you can call RaisePropertyChanged without actually implementing INPC.  That's why I asked.

Comment: ok, i just know that many other properties are set successfully (changed) and the binding take effect using RaisePropertyChanged so i can not yet understand why it is not showing the icon.png in the app when it clearly is setting the string to "icon.png" in the debugger.

Comment: do you have  `public class MyClassName : INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged() in `public class ExtendedBindableObject : BindableObject` inherits BindableObject which inherits INotifyPropertyChanged like: `public abstract class BindableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDynamicResourceHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to right click on **Resources/drawable/icon.png** then **Add To Project** and make sure **Build Action: AndroidResource**